# Is it possible to define time in a more universal way, such as, time is the outward manifestation of the activities inside an atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time

Is it possible to define time as the outward manifestation of the activities inside an atom?

For example,

- one second is defined as the unperturbed ground state hyperfine
  transition frequency of the caesium atom, which is 9192631770 Hz.

  But if the caesium atom travels at higher speeds, then the atom will
  have more kinetic energy which will slow down each activity inside
  the atom thus by taking more time to reach the value 9192631770 Hz
  than traditional "second". (times slows as speed increases ).
- Is it the same reason for slowing down the aging process of living
  being when it travels at higher speeds?

  Because each atom of the living being will have more kinetic energy
  which will slow down each activity inside the atom thus by slowing
  the aging process?
- Is it the same reason the time slows down as gravity increases ?

  Because higher gravity slow down each activity inside the atom.

Comment: There  are no atoms in the theory of relativity.

Comment: Time is what a clock measures: there is no more fundamental definition. Metrologists compare clocks and refine the practical definition according to how well different clocks agree with each other.

Comment: @WillO, Albert Einstein's theory of general relativity is based on the idea that massive objects cause a distortion in space-time. What is that massive objects made of?

Comment: Time in GR just re-uses the definition for time from SR, so mass is not involved.  Incidentally, Einstein's contribution was to _remove_ the physics (i.e. dynamics) aspects (refined soon afterwards by Minkowski), so there is nothing to be gained by re-introducing any of them!

Answer (score 2):

No, No and No:

1. The measurement is made in the atom's rest frame, or at least as close as experimentally possible.
2. This question violates one of my fundamental rules of studying physics: *Including the human body will* never *clarify a physics concept* . The aging process proceeds normally, as proper time ticks away. It's just from a moving reference frame, that time ticks more slowly compare with a clock in that other frame. Of course, the existence of other inertial frames can have no impact on one's own inertial frame. If it did, then you find a frame where the influence in minimized, *et voìla*: you have found The Absolute Rest Frame.
3. The strength of gravity does not affect proper time; rather, it is the gravitational potential difference (in weak fields where that still makes sense). For instance: the local $\vec g$ at the center of the Earth is $0$; however, the Earth's core is 2 years younger than the surface, since formation, because it is further down the potential well.

Comment: 1. Does that mean, the measurement  taken in atom's rest frame on earth will be the same as the measurement taken  in atom's rest frame in a space ship which hypothetically travel at 50% of the speed of light?

Comment: 2.  If two identical apple are taken and one is kept on earth and the other is kept in a space ship (same temperature /pressure/humidity as the other apple) which hypothetically travel at 50% of the speed of light. What will be the degradation rate of each apple? Does the degradation of apple / aging of apple will be slower in space ship?

Comment: 3.    The point was,  does the gravity affects passage of time? and when that is a fact , what does "Earth's core is 2 years younger than the surface" practically means? isn't it practically means that the atomic level activity was slow at earth's core compared to surface which kept the material at earth's core younger than surface?

Comment: Both your first two questions imply that you have not understood the *relativity* concept. "hypothetically travel at 50% of the speed of light?" **relative to what??**

Comment: In question 1, both atoms will be at rest: one atom will be at rest compared to Earth, with a space ship flying by somewhere. The other atom will be at rest compared to a space ship, with Earth flying by somewhere. The situation is symmetric.

Comment: The situation in question 2 is exactly the same. Both apples will be at rest in their own rest frame (by definition) and they cannot perform ANY experiments that will decide "which one is at rest and which one is moving at 50% light speed". They will *both* be at rest. Both will observe the other to be moving.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/does-time-tick-at-the-same-rate-for-everyone/   , https://www.technologyreview.com/2019/12/07/65014/how-does-time-dilation-affect-aging-during-high-speed-space-travel/

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, speed of light is the reference.

Comment: "speed of light is the reference" is not an answer. Things are not moving at 50% of the speed of light relative to the speed of light. One object is moving relative to another object. And the whole insight of special relativity is that light moves at the **same speed** relative to **any** object that is not accelerating. There is no such thing as "actually moving" or "actually being at rest". Nothing is more at rest than anything else that is not accelerating.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your suggestion seems to be trying to define time in a less universal way. However, leaving that aside...

To judge by your comments, you misunderstand the nature of time dilation in special relativity. It does not mean that moving clocks slow down. It means that the time interval between two events that occur in one place in one inertial frame will always be less than the time interval between the same two events in another frame in which they occur in different places.

Time dilation is an effect that arises from the geometry of spacetime. The interval between two events might be 5s in one frame, and 4s in another. Note that it is actually the time interval that differs between the two frames- it is nothing to do with clocks slowing down or speeding up. An accurate clock will simply tick off the time interval.

You also don't seem to appreciate that in SR time dilation is entirely reciprocal. If we are moving relative to each other, then I will seem time dilated relative to your frame and you will seem time dilated relative to mine. In SR the effect actually arises from the relativity of simultaneity, which causes clocks in your frame to be out of synch with clocks in mine. All of our clocks run at exactly the same rate, but they seem to be running slower when compared with each other because of the desynchronisation effects.

Limiting a definition of time to activities within an atom is missing the point. Take any other form of device for measuring time: a pendulum, for example, or a sun-dial or an hour glass- they would all seem time-dilated to someone passing in a rocket, and I doubt you would be able to explain the effect in terms of activities inside the atoms of which the various devices where formed. Indeed, take the classic light clock- the light bouncing between two parallel mirrors does not involve any atomic activity at all, so how would you account for a light clock appearing time dilated?

Answer (score 1):

Time is that which the clocks show.

The important thing is to understand what a clocks is: it's a physical system the has a local energy reservoir and a mechanism that releases this energy steadily and slowly towards infinity.

"Clock ticks" are the marks of this energy release. The reason why there is no universal time is then completely obvious: there is more than one clock. These energy reservoirs and clock mechanisms can exist in different places and physical environments. What the energy release of these clocks (the rate of their clock ticks) looks like from a location that is not right next to the clock depends, obviously, on the signal propagation between the clock and the observer. Relative motion will change the frequency of the received clock ticks and we are getting time dilation. So will gravity and this leads to gravitational redshift. It should also be fairly obvious that the mechanism of a clock doesn't really matter, because the "change in rate" happens during the energy flow between clock and observer. That atomic clocks are very precise is simply an artifact of atomic physic that we use to make precision measurements. To measure gravitational redshift in the lab, however, a Moessbauer spectroscopy experiment is easier, in which case "the clock" is made of radioactive nuclei. On a personal note, that's one of the most beautiful experiments that I know about. It's almost like magic that a sheet of radioactive material can make such precise "time" measurements.

Answer (score -3):

The answer to your question is yes.  Time is the outward manifestation of crossing a specified physical distance in spacetime.   Let me explain:

As you know, the entire basis of General Relativity is that space and time are intimately connected into what is normally called spacetime.  But for now let's keep them separate.

The theory of Loop Quantum Gravity (a reasonable alternative to string theory) speculates that space is particulate.  That is, space is made up of really really (1 x 10^-35 metres) small quantum fuzzy particles.  It is thought that when energy is added to these particles, such as the energy emanating from matter, the particles dilate or swell.

So if we think of a specified number of particles, then we can imagine that it takes light a certain time (eg 1 second) to cross those particles.  So lets imagine that in the distance of 3 x 10^8 metres, we have 3 x 10^42 particles in a row. We know that it takes light 1 second to travel that distance, or the length of that row.  If the particles are dilated near a planet, then it STILL takes light 1 second to cross that same number of particles.  Thus we have defined time as the period necessary to cross the physical distance of 3 x 10^42 particles, however those particles are defined. Thus we have a real definition of spacetime.  In distant space with no planets nearby, the particles will be as small as possible.  But near a planet the particles are dilated, and dilated even more near a star and a black hole.  However we look at it, 1 second is the manifestation of moving light across 3 x 10^42 particles.

Now lets look at kinetic time dilation.  We know that massless particles like photons travel at c.  But anything made of mass can never reach c and leads to kinetic time dilation.  Why does time dilate with velocity?  Remaining with Loop Quantum Gravity, I would say that any moving object will create a bow wave in the quantum field, and this transfers energy to particulate space and causes the dilation of those particles, and subsequent dilation of time.  Easy right?

All of this will be apparent in my speculative but now peer reviewed and soon to be publish paper on [Dilating Loop Relativity](https://zenodo.org/record/7591244#.ZCSfwMrMLq5)